# Unfortunately has stopped when using appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio, build-error

Now I'm using Android studio and try to use v7-appcompat.

I just updates my dependencies to

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

and change my Activity to extents ActionBarActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

It has no error when I run this.
But after execute app, I face into 'Unfortunately has stopped' message.
I don't know what's wrong.

and this is log-cat.

```
07-23 22:08:00.001      784-784/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d3a3a0 that 
    was originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId
    (AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-23 22:08:00.001      303-868/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find 
connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41621520
```